# Juju add-machine does not start LXD container

Tags: juju, maas, lxd

```
Juju agent version 2.3.4
MAAS version: 2.3.1 (6470-g036d646-0ubuntu1~16.04.1
```

I seem to be experiencing the symptoms akin to the ones [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/1642385).


With MAAS nodes in 'Ready' state, adding a machine

```
#juju add-machine lxd
```

picks one of them, deploys Ubuntu, but then fails to start lxd container

```
Machine  State    DNS              Inst id  Series  AZ       Message
0        started  135.111.102.194  wpdf6g   xenial  default  Deployed
0/lxd/0  down                      pending  xenial           failed to start machine 0/lxd/0 (can't get info for image 'juju/xenial/amd64': not found), retrying in 10s (6 more attempts)
```

```
juju debug-log
```

gives

```
machine-0: 20:13:48 WARNING juju.provisioner failed to start machine 0/lxd/0 (can't get info for image 'juju/xenial/amd64': not found), retrying in 10s (2 more attempts)
machine-0: 20:13:59 WARNING juju.provisioner incomplete DNS config found, discovering host's DNS config
```

Is

```
incomplete DNS config found
```

indicative of anything here ?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind ...
Inadvertently I renamed the Juju model, thus losing all the config options from config.yaml (including the proxies ...) in effect at bootstrap time that were inherited by "default" model.